# Two questions on surface fibrations

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth surface and $f\colon X\to B$ a fibration, with $B$ a smooth curve.

(Q1) Why is the normal bundle of any fiber $F$ trivial?

It is clear to me that it has to be of degree zero since $0=F^2=\deg(O_F(F))$, but why is $O_F(F)=O_F$ ?

For the second question I will assume that $B=\Bbb{P}^1$ and that $X$ is regular, i.e. $H^1(O_X)=0$.

(Q2) Why can we find a short exact sequence of the form
$$0\to\omega_X\to\omega_X\otimes O_X(F_1+\cdots+F_r) \to \oplus O_{F_i}\to0$$
where $r$ is big enough and $F_i$ are general fibres (I guess smooth is enough) ?

What I understand is that by adjunction and (Q1) for each smooth fibre $F$ we have an iso $\omega_X\otimes O(F)\simeq O_F$. But I do not manage to cook up a map as in the sequence above such that the kernel is $\omega_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F=f^{-1}(p)$, then the normal bundle is the pull back of the normal bundle of $p\in B$ and this of course is trivial. The second sequence doesn't look right. You should have $\omega_{F_i}$ s on the right. You always have the natural exact sequence, $0\to O_X\to O_X(F_1+\cdots+F_r)\to \oplus O_{F_i}\to 0$, since $O_{F}(F)=O_F$. Tensoring with $\omega_X$ and noting that by adujunction, $\omega_X\otimes O_F=\omega_F$, you get what I said.

Comment: Dear Mohan, thank you for the prompt answer. Here is the source paper: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/cortona81.pdf (see top of p.130)